# Generating Unit tests in Angular 16 (get ERR_REQUIRE_ESM from ngentest)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngentest

I am trying to generate unit tests from CLI generated app in Angular 16.

Used to do it with ngentest, however if I try that now, getting error:

```
\src\app> gentest app.component.ts        
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Angular\test\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of C:\Angular\coach-test\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:10:16)
    at requireFromString (C:\Users\olegk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ngentest\node_modules\require-from-string\index.js:28:4)
    at run (C:\Users\olegk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ngentest\index.js:159:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\olegk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ngentest\index.js:228:3) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Any easy way to fix it?
Or use some other way of generating unit tests in ng 16?

Please advise,
TIA, Oleg.

Comment: I am using VS Code.  It looks like ngentest is not updated since 2021. I also noticed that some unit tests were generated in that generated app by CLI.  I would like to try doing some TDD in Angular 16.  Is IntelliSense extension for VS Code a good candidate for that (or as a unit test generator)?